# Laravel Form Validation, fail if not empty

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have an input field which needs to be empty, otherwise I want the validation to fail. This is an attempt at stopping spam through a contact form.

I've looked at the documentation for the validation but there's nothing to do this, other than the "max" rule, but this doesn't work.

Any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method where you are validation, extend/add custom rule:

```
Validator::extend('mustBeEmpty', function($attr, $value, $params){
    if(!empty($attr)) return false;
    return true;
});
```

Then you may use this `rule` like:

```
protected $rules = array(
    'emptyInputField' => 'mustBeEmpty'
);
```

Then everything is as usual, just use:

```
$v = Validator::make(Input::except('_token'), $rules);
if($v->passes()) {
    // Passed, means that the emptyInputField is empty
}
```

There are other ways to do it without extending it like this or extending the `Validator` class but it's an easy `Laravelish` way to do it. Btw, there is a package available on `Github` as [Honeypot spam prevention for Laravel applications](https://github.com/msurguy/Honeypot), you may check that.

Comment: I tried the proposed "Honeypot spam prevention" and it has everything you need. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a clean and (probably) bullet-proof solution:

```php
    'mustBeEmpty'  => 'present|max:0',
```

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 8.x and above, you may use the `prohibited` validation rule:

```php
return [
   'emptyInputField' => 'prohibited',
];
```

Comment: I had to use `'emptyInputField' => 'nullable|prohibited',`, as otherwise the rule always triggered, even if an empty string was sent.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.8 you can use `sometimes` for conditional rules adding. `'email' => 'sometimes|email'` . This rules will be applied if there is something present in input field.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for.. the field always has to be empty..

Answer (score -1):

You can use the *empty* rule. Details can be seen here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.